# jQuery onchange event doesn't change value synchronously

Tags: jquery, onchange

I tried to submit value of 1 input field to other input field in the same form using jQuery synchronously. What I achieved is when the user changes focus from 1st field the value is changed in 2nd field, what I want to achieve is change the value of 2nd field as and when user changes it in the 1st field.
Here is my HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-label">Rate</label>
<div class="form-field">
<input type="text" name="rate_value" id="rate_value">
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<label class="form-label">Amount</label>
<div class="form-field">
<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" disabled>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is my jQuery code

```
var rate_value;
var amount;
$("#rate_value").on('change', function(){
    amount = $("#rate_value").val();
    $("#amount").val(amount);
});
```

Comment: your code already changes the values in the second field when the first changes.. what exactly do you need? Make sure you have it within `$(document).ready(function(){   /// you code here  });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)** event if you want to update disabled input after each key is pressing

```js
var rate_value;
var amount;
$("#rate_value").on('keyup', function() {
  amount = $("#rate_value").val();
  $("#amount").val(amount);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label">Rate</label>
  <div class="form-field">
    <input type="text" name="rate_value" id="rate_value">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label">Amount</label>
  <div class="form-field">
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update:** you can use **[`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)** event which is fired when the value of an `input` or `textarea` element is changed. It's better than `keyup` event, it only fires after released the pressed key. `input` event will fire at the time the value is changed.

```js
var rate_value;
var amount;
$("#rate_value").on('input', function() {
  amount = $("#rate_value").val();
  $("#amount").val(amount);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label">Rate</label>
  <div class="form-field">
    <input type="text" name="rate_value" id="rate_value">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label">Amount</label>
  <div class="form-field">
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But that leaves first element we input. I mean run the code snippet and you will know. Is there a way to update second field as and when first field is updated?